# My nav li are stretching outside their parents even though their width is set to max width 100%, does anyone know why?

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down menu and I noticed when it appeared a scroll bar appeared. I set it to display block so its constantly visible and changed its background color to red and I changed its parent's background color to blue, the drop down menu is taking up the width of its parent like it should but it looks like its parent the nav li with the class of main-nav are stretching out side its parent and taking the dropdown menus with the classes of sub nav with it. Does anyone know why main nav is stretching out side its parent?
I'm assuming it has something to do with the absolute positioning of the dropdown menu but I'm not entirely sure why or how to fix it

https://jsfiddle.net/93qft4d7/1/

```
    .main-nav li{
        background-color: blue;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0 5px;
        padding: 0;
        max-width: 100%;
        }
   .main-nav > li{
        float: left;
       }
  .sub-nav {
      background-color: red;
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
      position: absolute;
      padding: 0;
      max-width;
     }
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid to start..you have the `body` inside a div.

Answer (score 0):

When you give an element a `max-width`, it will take the width of the parent element - in this case your parent is 100% of that parent, which is 100% of the page. You either need to give the parent a set width or each `li` item it's own width.

Answer (score 0):

Add a position relative to the surrounding `li` elements:

Your CSS selector:

`.main-nav li`

Should get the rule:

`position:relative;`

```css
body {
    margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 max-width: 100%;
}
.main-layout{
 min-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}
header {
 background-color: orange;
    margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

header h1{
 float: left;
}


nav {
 background-color: yellow;
 float: right;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
    margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.main-nav {
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.main-nav li{
 background-color: blue;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0 5px;
 padding: 0;
 max-width: 100%;
  position:relative;
}
.main-nav > li{
 float: left;
}
.sub-nav {
background-color: red;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 0;
 max-width;
}

.main-nav li:hover .sub-nav {
 display: block;
}

section {
    margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.clearfix::after{
 content:"";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}
footer {
 height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-layout">
  <body>
   <header class="clearfix">
    <h1> This is a Test</h1>
    <nav>
  <ul class="main-nav">
   <li>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <span> Content 1</span>
    <ul class="sub-nav">
     <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
    <span> Content 2</span>
    <ul class="sub-nav">
     <li><a href="page4.html">Page 4</a></li>
     <li><a href="page5.html">Page 5</a></li>
     <li><a href="page6.html">Page 6</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
    <span>Content 3</span>
    <ul class="sub-nav">
     <li><a href="page7.html">Page 7</a></li>
     <li><a href="page8.html">Page 8</a></li>
     <li><a href="page9.html">Page 9</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
   </header>
   <section>
   </section>
   </div>
   <footer>
    <span>footer content</span>
   </footer>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The positioning context for the submenu should be the `li` not the parent `ul`.

```
.main-nav li{
    background-color: lightblue;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative; /* this */
}
```

Then everything works fine.

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
nav {
  background-color: yellow;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.main-nav {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.main-nav li {
  background-color: lightblue;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.main-nav > li {
  float: left;
}
.sub-nav {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  max-width;
}
.main-nav li:hover .sub-nav {
  display: block;
}
section {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
footer {
  height: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="main-nav">
    <li>
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span> Content 1</span>
      <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span> Content 2</span>
      <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li><a href="page4.html">Page 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="page5.html">Page 5</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="page6.html">Page 6</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Content 3</span>
      <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li><a href="page7.html">Page 7</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="page8.html">Page 8</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="page9.html">Page 9</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Code:
https://jsfiddle.net/93qft4d7/2/

Add these CSS styles

```
.main-nav > li{

  position:relative;

}

.sub-nav {

    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:100%;
}
```